# What is a structure function (or proton structure function)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, protons, scattering-cross-section

Can someone explain structure functions (proton structure functions)? I know they are used to study or understand the structure of protons , but does there exist a particular formula to calculate their value? Or are they measured from experiments? Is it a physical quantity?

Comment: can someone explain this in  layman language as I couldn't really understand this from pdfs.

Comment: This answer of mine on a  similar question may help https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1492What+is+meant+by+Proton+Structure+Function%3F

Comment: thankyou for your response, I did went through this and also through the blog you mentioned in the answer, but I'm still confused about how those structure functions are measured/ calculated?

Comment: actually I'm working on strong coupling constant, and am looking for things that are linked to the coupling constant. @annav

Comment: One does the scattering experiment that will give the plots in the answer. Then one uses theory to assume the contribution  of various partons and fit the theoretical curve to the data. https://cds.cern.ch/record/593898/files/0211086.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one thing that comes to *my* mind when thinking of the connection between the strong coupling constant $\alpha_{S}$ and the proton structure functions $F_{1}\left( x, Q^{2}\right)$ and $F_{2}\left(x, Q^{2} \right)$.

When you studied elastic electron-proton scattering (such as in Mott or Rutherford scattering), you might have come across the term *form factors* $G_{E}$ and $G_{M}$, where $G_{E}$ represents the a priori unknown charge distribution of the proton, and $G_{M}$ the magnetic moment distribution of the proton.

In deep inelastic scattering experiments, one calls the *structure functions*, though they do not have the same physical meaning as the form factors do in elastic electron-proton scattering. For example, the structure function $F_{2}\left( x, Q^{2}\right)$ (compared to elastic scattering, we need *two* independent variables to describe them, here chosen as $Q^{2} := -q^{2}$, where $q$ describes the four-momentum of the photon, and $x := \frac{Q^{2}}{2qP}$ describes the Björken scaling $x$) describes the probability to find a quark with the momentum fraction $x$ in the proton (this is the meaning of the Björken scaling $x$, it gives you the momentum fraction the quark participating in the scattering takes from the total proton momentum $P$).

One can now define relations for $F_{1}\left( x, Q^{2}\right)$ and $F_{2}\left(x, Q^{2} \right)$ (I do not want to elaborate on this here, please take a look at Mark Thomson's "Modern Particle Physics", chapters 8.2.1 and 8.3 if you are interested) , and in doing so, one assumes that the electron scatters off from a quark in the proton *elastically*. This is very important, so let me repeat: The scattering of the electron with the **proton** is **inelastic**, but we assume that it is *elastic* with a (point-like) *quark* inside the proton.

However, why do we assume this? The reason for that is the running of the coupling constant $\alpha_{S}$. Now, at high values of $Q^{2}$ ($= -q^{2}$), we know that $\alpha_{S}$ rapidly decreases, and thus we talk about *asymptotic freedom*, which basically means that the quarks inside the proton can be described as quasi-free particles in the proton for high enough $Q^{2}$.

This plot might help in understanding (taken from (1)):

[image]

(1) https://dispatchesfromturtleisland.blogspot.com/2018/06/measuring-strong-force-coupling-constant.html, accessed 14/02/2021